# Has someone proposed this hypothesis before? (Flashlight Hypothesis)

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

Recently, I've been thinking about cool, weird theorems and I wanted to try to come up with my own. So, I created my own "Flashlight Hypothesis". It's decently ridiculous, but if no one has proposed it, can I make a theorem out of it? Here it is:

Imagine someone shining a flashlight at a mirror. It would take two mirrors to reflect the light back into the flashlight to create a triangle.

Figure of what I'm describing:

[image]

The rules is that it *has* to be a triangle, meaning that the light that gets reflected back at the flashlight must line up with the beam that comes out of the flashlight.

> My Flashlight Hypothesis states that the flashlight will never be on the hypotenuse.

I know that it's a pretty obvious statement, but lots of theorems seem to be built on these simple truths so others can use them to create some pretty complex conclusions. I was wondering if I could somehow do something with this idea or if another person has come up with a similar idea.

Thank you!

Edit: So this has been disproven when considering triangles that are not right triangles, but does it still stand for all right triangles?

Edit 2: Alright this is VERY disproven, thank you!

Comment: It takes three mirrors... and also clearly the flashlight can be placed anywhere on any side of the triangle and the light will still go round the triangle, so it can be on the hypotenuse!

Comment: I applaud your trying to think up something like this -- that's part of how mathematics gets done. But I think the prior comment makes a good point. You might also find it nice to consider more general triangles than right-triangles, in which case "hypotenuse" doesn't really even make sense.

Comment: Wow! Thank you George R, that makes a lot of sense. Well, I guess I've had my first hypothesis disproven. I think I got stuck thinking in terms of strictly right triangles. I'm confused as to why hypotenuse doesn't makes sense, though, for right triangles, in response to John.

Comment: @EthanG: Consider a flashlight that emits a red beam of light from one end and a blue beam from its other end. Place a mirror *anywhere you like* in the path of the red beam, turned *at any angle you like*. A mirror placed in the path of the blue beam can be turned so that reflected blue beam crosses the reflected red beam. At the cross-point, a mirror turned *just so* will make the re-reflected red beam follow the blue's path, and vice versa. In this way, you can make a triangle of any shape you like. In particular, you can make a right triangle whose right angle occurs at any of the mirrors.

Comment: @Blue Ah! Your visualization makes a lot of sense. I now see you can create any triangle and have the flashlight be any side. Darn. Still fun to try to come up with this stuff, though!

Comment: @EthanG: *"Still fun to try to come up with this stuff, though!"* I absolutely agree ... even after having been at it for a while longer than you. :)  Mathematics is a creative art, after all, so keep at it!